# Fetch with Session ID in ember JS

Tags: http, servlets, ember.js, fetch

i am a newbie in ember and servlet. Here is the code snippet of dashboard.js from the route directory.

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class DashboardRoute extends Route {

    async model()
    {
        let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/Servlet/getfilename");
        let data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
}
```

I have maintained Session in my Servlet (i.e) When an user logged in via login Page LoginServlet will create a Session for the request and redirects the user to the Dashboard Page, where it fetches a json response from another servlet which does a session validation. Now that throws an error saying that the **Session is null**.Why does this happen? Is there is way to store the Session ID in ember and send it to the servlet via fetch?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to look over these docs from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

*potentially*, adding this to your fetch request's options:

```js
    credentials: 'same-origin',
```

more information on credentials can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

Comment: I added ```credentials: 'include'```, and that worked for me. Thank You!!!